# How read Common Data Format (CDF) in Python

Tags: python, io, dataformat, common-data-format

I need to read CDF file with using python. I have found libraries but i did not understand how use it. For example at this([Python lib](http://spacepy.lanl.gov/doc/pycdf.html)), i need to download CDF lib, i don't know where to download. There is download page for CDF but it seems irrelevant with this library.

Comment: are looking for this page: http://pythonhosted.org/CDF/getting.html ?

Comment: @AndreHolzner, I did not see it. how can i install this egg files?

Comment: @seleucia - you should consider accepting an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37232129/907921) by @miraculixx is correct, but it assumes that you have already installed the [CDF C Library](https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/).

Here's an easy to follow guide if you didn't even know what the CDF file format was before you found this question on SO.

**1. Download the latest version of the CDF C Library:**

You can find the latest stable release at this [link](https://spdf.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/software/cdf/dist/latest-release/linux/). Grab the source code using `wget`, and extract it. **Note:** the following will create a directory in the current folder `./` if you want to download the code in a different path make sure you change the code below.

```
wget -r -l1 -np -nd -nc http://cdaweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/software/cdf/dist/latest-release/linux/ -A cdf*-dist-all.tar.gz
tar xf cdf*-dist-all.tar.gz -C ./
cd cdf*dist
```

**2. Install all the dependencies:**

[SpacePy](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/pycdf.html) and the CDF Library have several dependencies (as pointed out by @Michal Dyzma). You can install them all using [conda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/), and [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

```
pip install numpy scipy h5py matplotlib networkx
apt install build-essential gfortran libncurses5-dev
```

**3. Compile the C Library:**

You should have downloaded a `README.install` file that contains a lot more details on this step than I'll provide. The two cents are that you want to check which compile variables are required/optional for your system and needs.

```
make all.help
```

I will be building the distribution for Linux using the GNU C compiler. I am not interested in the FORTRAN interface, and my operating system supports shareable libraries. I want to install the Curses-based toolkit programs that allow to use the command-line based interactive CDF tools (that's why we installed `libncurses5-dev` dependency in step 2). As a result this is the final make command:

```
make OS=linux ENV=gnu CURSES=yes FORTRAN=no UCOPTIONS=-O2 SHARED=yes -j4 all
make install #no sudo
```

Installation should run smooth and add all the files in the `./bin`, `./include`, and `./lib` sub-directories.

**4. Set the environment variables:**

There should be a file in `./bin` called `definitions.B` that does this automatically for you, make it executable with `chmod+x` and add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` (**Note:** 1) I'm assuming you installed the library at the path `$HOME/Libraries/`; 2) There is a space after the `.`):

```
. $HOME/Libraries/cdf/cdf36_3-dist/bin/definitions.B
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
The file above has a bug at **line 68**, instead of appending to environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it overwrites it. The fix is easy, replace **line 68** with the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Libraries/cdf/cdf36_3-dist/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If for some reason `definitions.B` is not there, simply add the following:

```
export CDF_BASE=$HOME/Libraries/cdf/cdf36_3-dist
export CDF_INC=$CDF_BASE/include
export CDF_LIB=$CDF_BASE/lib
export CDF_BIN=$CDF_BASE/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CDF_BASE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**5. You're all set, go and do good:**

Assuming you installed `spacepy` with pip the following should work out of the box:

```
from spacepy import pycdf
cdf = pycdf.CDF('/path/to/file.cdf')
print(cdf)
```

Comment: Very helpful. But is NASA actually not providing packages for common packaging systems (Ubuntu/Debian, RPM, etc)? Seriously?  Asking end users to do this kind of manual building of packages, rather than using a package managment system with upgrades for security issues and bug fixes integrated into a standard upgrade mechanism, is dangerous and a big imposition. Or am I missing something basic about typical users?

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Very nice explanation.  I was surprised to see no useful results in a google search for an example cdf file, but finally found several in the distribution itself, e.g. in `cdf36_3-dist/samples/cacsst2.cdf`

Comment: The link for the latest stable release is dead

Answer (score 3):

If you have Python's package tool, [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) installed, you can get the spacepy cdf library as follows:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/spacepy/spacepy.git
```

Note this will install a lot of dependencies, including numpy and scipy. These can be a bit difficult to install from scratch. You might want to install a ready-made package first, e.g. [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Once that's done, just use the above command and spacepy should install like a breeze.

Once the installation of spacepy was successful, according to this [example](http://spacepy.lanl.gov/doc/pycdf.html#read-a-cdf) it should work something like this:

```
from spacepy import pycdf
cdf = pycdf.CDF('/path/to/file.cdf')
print(cdf)
```

Comment: During installation I'm getting this error: extension 'ffnet.fortran._ffnet' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found

Comment: did you install anaconda?

Comment: Yes, i'm using anaconda.

Comment: well apparently your system lacks a fortran compiler - [this might help](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries).  I'm starting to wonder, do you need any other functionality from spacepy other than the CDF part?

Comment: I installed but now i'm getting another error :  Exception: Cannot load CDF C library from .Try os.environ["CDF_LIB"] = library_directory before import.
. I tried to set library_directory but i don't know where is it?

Comment: @seleucia: have you found the solution for your problem? I have the same issue

Comment: @hoangtran - You can check my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

While ago I had same problem. I assume, you work on Windows...

According to Spacepy documentation you need several dependencies to use its's cdf module.

**First** of all it SpacePy officially supports only 32-bit python version, therefore you have to have python in 323bit.

**Second**, it requires NASA CDF library installed in you system (also 32 bit version). You can grab it from 
[here](http://cdaweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/software/cdf/dist/cdf36_2/).

**Third** proceed with Spacepy dependencies:

- numpy
- scipy
- matplotlib
- h5py
- networkx
- ffnet

Most of them are part of Anaconda bundle. If they are not and you have to install them simply `pip install <package name>`.

If you have problems with compiling from the sources, I advice to go to Christoph Gohlke web site and grab pre-built binaries for Windows matching your python version.
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

This should get you going with Spacepy CDF module.

You can also try another approach. Download CDF-to-netCDF converter from NASA page and run it on your CDF file.

Python has nice netCDF module, which can be installed from GitHub, or python repo. In this case you also need several dependencies like HDF5, netCDF-4, numpy, cython.

Once you have netCDF file, you can access it with netCDF module or `scipy.io` module.

Answer (score 2):

Maven's CDFLib is a pure python alternative.
https://github.com/MAVENSDC/cdflib

`pip install cdflib`

In your code :

```
import cdflib

cdf_file = cdflib.CDF('/path/to/cdf_file.cdf')
```

Comment: You can also write CDF files with this library.

Comment: Hello! I have been trying to use cdflib and I wanted to see the contents of a file but was not able to find out how to do it. Could you provide a line of code to help me with that? Thanks!